# How do you test your blackberry application on the device?

Tags: testing, blackberry, device

This may sound very noobish, but I can't seem to get my app to my blackberry.

I was trying to follow the beginning blackberry development book's guide, but maybe I just missed the point somewhere.

For remote download, Is it really as simple as drop the COD and JAD files in the same folder on your server then just navigate to the URL with your device's browser? The book says it should prompt a download screen, but all I get is a page full of cryptic characters.

My app is a simple slideshow. Uses no signed things and is not MDS enabled. Did I forget something?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Just a few things that came to mind.  1) Are you going to the JAD file or the COD file?  You should be going to the JAD file.
2)Is the app larger than 64k?  In that case the COD file is actually a zipped file containing multiple files and needs to be split up for over the air installs
3) Have you tried installing from a USB cable?

Comment: I found the problem. It was larger than 64k, but that wasn't the issue. For some reason the JAR was saying there was 21 COD files when there was only 19. I don't know why it was saying there were more CODs than there really were, but after I removed the extras it worked fine... except all my bugs, but that's the point of device testing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it during development is to use javaloader:

```
javaloader.exe -u load myapp.cod
```

Where "myapp.cod" is the single COD file generated by the rapc compiler (and optionally signed if required).

If you do want to install it "OTA" (over the air) from your webserver, make sure you are deploying the JAD file and individual COD files (if it's a large app).  Also make sure that your [webserver MIME types are set properly for the .jad and .cod file extensions](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800708/800646/What_Is_-_The_required_MIME_types_for_a_web_server_to_serve_BlackBerry_applications.html?nodeid=1050153&vernum=0).

Answer (score 0):

You could true bluetooth the COD and JAD files to your blackberry